# Vuejs Laravel blankpage on IE and Safari

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

My webapp work correctly on Chrome and Firefox but not with IE8-11 and Safari.
I use Laravel 5.6 and the last version of `VueJS` (with laravelmix webpack).

I supposed that the `const` variable type is not readable by IE and Safari (
I think it would be necessary to compile es6 in es5).

I've tried import babel in app.js file but also many library but with no result:

```
- npm install es6-promise
- npm i --save @babel/polyfill
- npm i babel-polyfill
- npm i bufferutil --save -optional
- .babelrc file in root
- npm i --save-dev babel-preset-stage-2
- npm i --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
- npm i --save-dev babel-preset-env
- npm i joi-browser
- npm i --save-dev babel-preset-es2015-node6
- npm i --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

Or laravelmix file (webpack.mix.js) should be able to with the right config?

I've tried also this: 
- in webpack.mix.js file

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

 mix.webpackConfig({
   node: {
     fs: 'empty'
   }
 });
// mix.webpackConfig({

//   module: {
//     rules: [
//       {
//         test: /\.js?$/,
//         use: {
//           loader: 'babel-loader',
//           options: {
//             presets: ['es2015'] // default == env
//           }
//         }
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// });

// OR

// mix.webpackConfig({
//         module: {
//             rules: [{
//                 test: /\.js?$/,
//                 exclude: /(bower_components)/,
//                 use: [{
//                     loader: 'babel-loader',
//                     options: mix.config.babel()
//                 }]
//             }]
//         }

//     });
```

.babelrc file:

```
 {
     "presets": ["es2015"]
 }
```

and

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "browsers": ["IE >= 9", "> 1%"]
      }
    ],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}
```

If you have solutions or had a similar case, do not hesitate.
I've already searched on the web and by myself but nothing work.
If you need more information, tell me in comment.

EDIT:
ERROR MSG : SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode. (safari)

Comment: Vue does not work in IE8

Comment: Adding a source for @visevo's comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html. Which version of Safari are you testing on?

Comment: but my webapp not work in IE11,10,9,8... (all version). And with translate es6 to es5, IE 11-9 should work. But for IE8 if I translate es6 to es5 and es5 to es4 it's work or it's very impossible for iE8 ?

Comment: It's very impossible for IE8: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/935#issuecomment-111592458

Comment: @ChrisForrence I testing on v9.1.2, if the version < 11.1, it's impossible to work ? Because on IE 11 I've the same error but IE 11 support vuejs. SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode. 
I do not know how to translate to es5 correctly

Comment: where we should save `.babelrc` file